# Mips, how do i print all the numbers greater than 10

Tags: mips

How do I write a MIPS code to print all the numbers that larger than 10 in an array?

Assume:

- the array exists in the memory block;
- the starting address is in register `$t0;`
- the size of the array is in register `$t1;`

This is one of the questions appearing on my review sheet for the final exam, and I have no clue about it. Therefore, I hope anyone one good with MIPS can help me out with this.

Comment: Hint: You'll need to look up the MIPS assembler opcodes to add registers, register and constants, how do comparisons and branches work, how effective addresses work, how to load elements of arrays, understand how to call a function like printn or what have you, including how to pass an argument to it.  One approach is to write it in C and compile it to assembler, then study the assembler.

Answer (score 0):

If this is on your final exam study sheet then you should probably understand the basic syntax already, that said, you need to initialize a counter value, and set that in one of your temp registers, say $t2, you start it at zero. Each iteration through your code at the end you perform:

```
bgt $t2, $t1, BEGINNING_OF_LOOP
```

This tells you if you've looped through the array yet. You store 10 in one of your registers, say $t3, and each loop through the array you grab the value at $t0, increment the register by the length of a word, and check to see if the value is greater than 10:

```
lw $t4, $t0
addi $t0, $t0, 4
bgt $t4, 10, CODE_TO_PRINT_VARIABLE
```

This should get you on your way, but you are going to need to understand the basics of MIPS in order to answer a question like this. I suggest you write out this short program if you have time. If you can see the control structures in action at least once it helps cement the concepts in your mind. Hope this helps, good luck!